# Recursively strip pattern from filename?

Tags: shell, sed

Is there a way for me to use the find command to recursively loop through a directory and strip a pattern from the filename?

For example, if I have:

```
styles.css?c=123456
```

as a saved file, I would like to be able to loop through the files and match anything that has the wildcard `*.css?*` and then turn that `styles.css?c=123456` into `styles.css`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -type f -name '*.css*' -exec echo 'FILE="{}"; mv ${FILE} ${FILE%\?*} ' \; | bash
```